# Store/Save & Retrieve to/from SharedPreference Failure

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, live-wallpaper, edittextpreference

I've been having so much problem with this Live Wallpaper.
I have read alot online about these, and I thought I understood and got them.
When I tried to apply them to this live wallpaper, everything has been going very rough.
I've spent all day and night :-(

**Could you someone please help me out?**

My goal is to store the new password from edittextpreference to the

Sharedpreference, and then retrieve this password to compared with the login

password to if they are matched.

For example,

I have 2 edittextpreferences:

1) is for create new password which will be saved to the SharedPreference

2) is for login password.

The users will be granted the access when the login password is matched with the
one in the SharedPreference.

Please help me out,
I would be appreciated for your help.

prefs.java Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}


public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
{

}
}
{       

 SharedPreferences mlogin_password =  this.getSharedPreferences("data_storage", MODE_PRIVATE);  
    Editor login_password = mlogin_password.edit();
    login_password.putString("login", "login_pw2");     
    login_password.commit(); 



        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
        String s = sp.getString("login", null);
```

Sorry for 10000000 of error codes :-(

Logcat:

```
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:60)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:65)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:65)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:62)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:62)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:62)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:62)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:62)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:64)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:66)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:63)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:65)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:75)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:75)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more


at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
at rare_war.weapons.prefs.<init>(prefs.java:68)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to store the new password from edittextpreference to the
>   Sharedpreference...

Not a good idea. You shouldn't store passwords on `SharedPreferences`

I would suggest using a different approach like storing the encrypted password on a server and then check what the user entered against it.

Please, also make sure you read the Android guide on [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Thanks for reply, do the users have to have internet in order to login since you mentioned?  Well, this password is not really personal stuff, so I thought it would easy to go with SharedPreference, but I guess not.  It looks easy, but pain in the ...

Comment: Yes, they need to have an internet connection to connect to the server. Did you read the `SharedPreferences` docs from the link above?

Comment: Could you explain about (PREFS_NAME, 0)?   I need to save 3 different passwords: new_password, confirm_new_pw, and log in_password.  Do I only need 1 or 3 different PREFS_NAME's?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are saving password on sharedPreference named 'data_storage' and retrieving from default sharedPreference thats why you are not getting saved password.Try to save and retrieve preference value from same sharedPreference.

Comment: I even tried the 1st set of coded (to store) and commented the 2nd set of codes (to retrieve), it still gave me a bunch of error codes. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.... very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use getSharedPreferences for the key "data_storage" and not for getDefaultSharedPreferences, in other words, Context? I'm not really sure about it, but you should try.

The mechanism works as follows: you save the key under a string name "date_storage" then you retrieve they key. In both cases you need to get the SharedPreferences with the line:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
```

After that use the "sp.get()" methods to get the required value for the saved string key ("data_storage").

Comment: ahh I see that would give me the default value (good catch, thank you), but even so, it shouldn't give me errors though. what does it mean by "Context"?  Sorry for noob question...  Thank you very much